# How building XPath query?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have file xml and i want generate XPath code. How get "t" only for "r"= Nancy Meyers? How create this query? Have you any idea for resolve this problem? Many thanks!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <s>
  <f nr="nr1">
    <t>Piraci z Karaibow</t>
    <r>Gore Verbinski</r>
    <o>
      <a>Johnny Depp</a>
      <a>Geoffrey Rush</a>
      <a>Orlando Bloom</a>
      <a>Keira Knightley</>
    </o>
  </f>
  <f nr="nr2">
    <t>Czego pragna kobiety</t>
    <r>Nancy Meyers</r>
    <o>
      <a>Mel Gibson</a>
      <a>Helen Hunt</a>
      <a>Marisa Tomei</a>
    </o>
  </f>
<s>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xpath: `/s/f[r='Nancy Meyers']/t`